# getting error on IOS nativescript. but working on android

Tags: angular, native, nativescript-angular

> ***** Fatal JavaScript exception - application has been terminated. *****
> NativeScript encountered a fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'titleTextAttributes' of undefined
> at
> setColor(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/action-bar/index.ios.js:264:0)
> at [color:setNative](file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/action-bar/index.ios.js:355:0)
> at applyAllNativeSetters(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/properties/index.js:1094:0)
> at initNativeView(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/properties/index.js:1021:0)
> at onResumeNativeUpdates(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/index.js:695:22)
> at _resumeNativeUpdates(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/index.js:259:0)
> at onLoaded(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/index.js:214:0)
> at (file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/index.js:297:0)
> at callFunctionWithSuper(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/index.js:291:0)
> at callLoaded(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/index.js:297:0)
> at loadView(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/index.js:437:0)
> at (file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/index.js:216:0)
> at eachChildView(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/page/page-common.js:100:0)
> at eachChild(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view/view-common.js:700:0)
> at onLoaded(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/index.js:215:0)
> at onLoaded(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/page/index.ios.js:312:0)
> at (file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/index.js:297:0)
> at callFunctionWithSuper(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/index.js:291:0)
> at callLo<…>

Hello i was using nativescript to develop a mobile app. my App is all good and running on android. but when i try to run it on IOS device/emulator, i get this error. Can't figure out what the error is about.
I get this error when i try to tap on a button that navigates me to another page.
can someone give me advice please.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using nativescript/theme and loading node-sass, sass-loader.
Nativescript theme wants to style the Actionbar which raises an exception.

I managed to solve this by removing node-sass, sass-loader from the dev,  updated nativescript/theme to 3.0.1, updated to webpack 3.0.9, and added sass 1.32.8 to dev.